# How to make strings same byte size

Tags: java, string, byte

first I have a string, I add spaces with rightPadZeros() which put spaces till validNameLenght which represents number of valid characters alocated for string.

```
    this.name = rightPadZeros(str, validNameLenght);
```

for example: validNameLenght=7; str= "Adam"; then this.name = "Adam   ";

I try to convert my data to byte array

```
ByteArrayOutputStream hlpByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
hlpOutStream = new DataOutputStream(hlpByteArrayOutputStream);

hlpOutStream.writeUTF(this.name);
hlpOutStream.writeUTF(this.surname);

hlpByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

Now when I call hlpOutStream.size(); it returns number of bytes in array.

I want this size to be equal for whatever input and it works if I do not use special characters. I assume they have extra byte for character.

TESTS:

```
name=ADAM => size 22
name=James => size 22
name=Ňaa => size 23
```

I need the string to be the same lenght and wonder, how could I achieve this.

Comment: Did you happen to read the [documentation for the writeUTF method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: I understand that, thank you, but how can I make it/handle it to be same size?

Comment: Well, the documentation explains how many bytes are used for each character, depending on its value. So, count the bytes, and append the necessary number of white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of UTF bytes to be the same, you'll need to not pad the original strings with spaces to a common length, but compute the UTF length of the original strings, and determine the number of bytes to add to that, and then add that number of spaces.